# How can I check the values store on Arraylist before I insert a new values in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem on how can I check first if the values is already store on arraylist before I insert it on arraylist.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ArrayList.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains.aspx) method.

But better consider using a `List<T>` class instead of ArrayList.